# Ultracategories with one object

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic, semigroups-and-monoids, categorical-logic, stone-duality

Historically, the theory of ultracategories was invented [by Makkai](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/000187088790020X) to prove a strong conceptual completeness theorem for first-order logic, roughly: if $T$ and $S$ are two first-order theories such that the ultracategory of models of $T$ is equivalent to the ultracategory of models of $S$, then the theories $T$ and $S$ are "essentially the same" (their pretopos completions are equivalent).

There is some more recent material about ultracategories by Lurie, see [here](https://www.math.ias.edu/~lurie/278x.html) and [here](https://www.math.ias.edu/~lurie/papers/Conceptual.pdf), which uses a simplified definition of the notion of an ultracategory (which is, for the purposes of proving a strong conceptual completeness theorem, equivalent to Makkai's original definition). The [definition](https://www.math.ias.edu/~lurie/278xnotes/Lecture25X-Ultracategories.pdf) (see Definition 7) is still technical, though. So it is natural to ask if one can formulate this notion in more familiar terms when considering special cases of the notion of a category. Indeed, [an ultraset turns out to be the same as a compact Hausdorff space](https://www.math.ias.edu/~lurie/278xnotes/Lecture26X-Ultrasets.pdf) (Theorem 9).

I wonder if the notion of an ultracategory simplifies to something more familiar if we restrict to categories which are not a set, but a *monoid* or a *preordered set*:

- What is an ultracategory with exactly one object? (Call these things *ultramonoids*.)
- What is an ultracategory with at most one morphism between any pair of objects?

Coming back to the original motivation of ultracategories, an ultracategory usually consists of [structures in the sense of model theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_(mathematical_logic)). Let $\mathbf A$ be a structure. Can we equip, say, the endomorphism monoid $\mathrm{End}(\mathbf A)$ of $\mathbf A$ or the monoid $\mathrm{End}'(\mathbf A)$ of elementary embeddings $\mathbf A\hookrightarrow\mathbf A$ with the structure of an ultramonoid?

More generally, if $\mathcal M$ is any ultracategory and $M\in\mathcal M$ an object, is $\mathrm{End}(M)$ an ultramonoid? If $F\colon\mathcal M\to\mathcal N$ is an ultrafunctor, is for each $M\in\mathcal M$ the induced map $\mathrm{End}(M)\to \mathrm{End}(F(M))$ an ultrafunctor between ultramonoids?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$\newcommand{\cat}{\mathrm}
\newcommand{\St}{\cat{Stone}^\cat{fr}}
\newcommand{\Cat}{\cat{Cat}}
\newcommand{\Cart}{\cat{Cart}}
\newcommand{\Fun}{\cat{Fun}}
\newcommand{\Mon}{\cat{Mon}}
\newcommand{\Set}{\cat{Set}}
\newcommand{\Po}{\cat{Poset}}$
EDIT : I misread the definition of ultracategory fibration, apparently only *certain* locally cartesian edges are closed under composition. After a thought about it, what I said for monoids remains true, but not for posets. I just need to modify the arguments.

I would argue that a monoid is not the same as a category with one object, namely a monoid is the same as a *pointed* category with one object. This is not really relevant if you look at the category of categories as a $1$-category (because then $\hom_\Cat(BM, BM')$ is indeed isomorphic to $\hom_\Mon(M,M')$), but it does if you more naturally view it as a $(2,1)$-category ($\Fun(BM,BM')$ has nontrivial morphisms !)

In particular, I'll interpret your question as :

> What is an ultracategory $\mathcal M$ with a morphism from the terminal ultracategory "$*$" such that for all $I$, $*_{\beta I}\to \mathcal M_{\beta I}$ is essentially surjective ?

Of course, because $*_{\beta I}\simeq \prod_I*$ in a way compatible with $\mathcal M_{\beta I}\simeq \prod_I\mathcal M_*$, this is equivalent to $*\to \mathcal M_*$ being essentially surjective.

The first question is : What is a pointed ultracategory ?

In my original post, I made a mistake because I had misread the definition of ultrcategory. In particular, a morphism $\St\to \mathcal M$ is more than just a point in $\mathcal M_*$ : it's a point with a certain property. Namely, (see definition 1 in Lurie's notes) we ask that the comparison morphisms for base-change functors associated to *all* compositions $\beta I\to \beta J\to \beta K$ be isomorphisms when applied to this point (while in the definition of an ultracategory, one only requires this if $\beta I \to \beta J$ comes from a map $I\to J$).

But, in particular, if this point is the only point of $\mathcal M_*$ (and thus of $\mathcal M_{\beta I}$ for all $I$), this amounts to asking that cartesian morphisms actually be closed under composition ! In other words,

> An ultramonoid is an ultracategory which is a *cartesian* fibration $\mathcal M\to \St$ with a section $\St\to \mathcal M$ sending cartesian edges to cartesian edges, such that on fibers over $*$, the map $*\to \mathcal M_*$ is essentially surjective.

Now that this is clarified, the rest of my answer essentially goes through without changes. But note that there was initially a mistake, and also note that this will not work for posets !

The second thing to observe is that there is a functor $\Mon\to\Cat_*$ which implements the equivalence of $(2,1)$-categories I've mentioned above.

This functor is fully faithful (in fact it has a right adjoint - given by $(C,x)\mapsto \cat{End}_C(x)$, this will be relevant later - and the unit map $M\to \cat{End}_{BM}(\bullet)$ is an isomorphism), and therefore the functor $\Fun((\St)^\cat{op}, \Mon)\to \Fun((\St)^\cat{op},\Cat)$ is also fully faithful.

By what was clarified above, ultramonoids can therefore be viewed as a full subcategory of $\Fun((\St)^\cat{op},\Cat_*)$, via the Grothendieck construction (while this is not the case for general ultracategories ! for them it would be certain pseudo-functors). Precisely, it is the full subcategory spanned by functors $(\St)^\cat{op}\to\Cat_*$ that send the diagrams $(\{i\}\to \beta I)_{i\in I}$ to product diagrams. Piecing things together, using the fact that $\Mon\to\Cat_*$ and $\Cat_*\to\Cat$ both reflect and preserve products, we find :

> The category of ultramonoids is equivalent to the full subcategory of $\Fun((\St)^\cat{op},\Mon)$ spanned by those functors that send the diagrams $(\{i\}\to \beta I)_{i\in I}$ to product diagrams.

But we can be more concrete. Indeed, $\Fun((\St)^\cat{op},\Mon)\simeq \Mon(\Fun((\St)^\cat{op},\Set))$, and $\Mon \to \Set$ preserves and reflects products, so that :

> The category of ultramonoids is equivalent to the category of monoids in the category of ultrasets.

(note that for ultrasets the subtlety disappears: the fibrations must be cartesian, and not only locally cartesian)

Ultrasets are compact Hausdorff topological spaces, so finally:

**Corollary** : The category of ultramonoids is equivalent to the category of monoids in compact Hausdorff topological spaces.

Now,  if $\mathcal M$ is an ultracategory with a point $x : *\to \mathcal M_*$, there is, in general, no way to make an ultramonoid out of it because of this cartesian vs locally cartesian business. However, if it is a "nice" point, i.e. if it is a point for which the comparison morphisms for general compositions $\beta I\to \beta J\to \beta K$ are isomorphisms, then we can view it as a morphism $\St\to \mathcal M$ of ultracategory fibrations. In particular we can take the full subcategory $\mathcal M_x$ of $\mathcal M$ spanned by the image of $\St$, and this should still be an ultracategory fibration. But now this is a pointed ultracategory fibration with an essentially surjective point, so it is an ultramonoid, as explained above.

We therefore find tha a sufficiently nice object $x$ (in more details: a point $\St\to \mathcal M$) in an ultracategory $\mathcal M$ has an ultramonoid of endomorphisms, $\cat{End}_\mathcal M(x)$, i.e. a compact Hausdorff topological space of endomorphisms.

(For posets, I don't know a satisfying answer. I'm not sure you will get a more satisfying answer than to the question "what is an ultracategory ?", but I would be interested in seeing one)

EDIT to answer the questions in a comment below (rather than as a long sequence of further comments):

1- I used "pointed category" to mean something more naive than in the nLab, namely a category $C$ with a point $*\to C$. Morphisms of such are functors $f : C\to D$ that preserve the point, and $2$-morphisms are natural transformations that are the identity on the point (this is an unfortunate clash of terminology: one can define a "pointed object" in an arbitrary category, and "pointed objects of $Cat$" do not coincide with the nLab's pointed categories). With this definition, the (usual) $1$-category of monoids is equivalent to the $(2,1)$-category of pointed categories for which the point $*\to C$ is essentially surjective.

2- "which question": I was adressing the question about ultramonoids (at first I thought also posets, but in the end, no). I don't know if I'm using the same definition of ultramonoid as you are, because it's unclear to me what "an ultracategory with one object" means in the same way that it's unclear to me what "a category with one object" means.

If you mean in the strictest sense and using Definition 7, then no I am not using the same definition (a choice which my first paragraph tries to explain). There are 2 reasons I did not use the same definition: a- what I explained in the first paragraph of this (partial) answer and b- the strict definition is not invariant under the several presentations of "ultracategories" and not invariant under equivalence of ultracategories. I know that this means I'm not technically answering your question (in any case, I wasn't answering all of it, this was just a contribution ! I'm sorry if I made it sound like it was supposed to be everythin). But maybe in the situation you're interested in, the definition I used might be more relevant ?

3- The notation $*_{\beta I}\to \mathcal M_{\beta I}$ refers to $*^I\to \mathcal M^I$ in the language of definition 7, specifically the map that picks out this one object. Sorry again, Definition 1 was clearer to me, which is why I phrased my answer in this language (note that the two definitions are equivalent in a suitable sense).

4- I define the $(2,1)$-category of ultramonoids as a full subcategory of the category of pointed ultracategories (in the sense I described earlier). In particular, morphism *categories* (rather than morphism sets) are categories of ultrafunctors and, I guess but am not sure about the terminology, ultra natural transformations.

5- A "point" of a category is an object therein, equivalently a functor $*\to C$. I used this latter perspective (which may seem unnecessarily pedantic) to define a point of an ultracategory, as an ultrafunctor from the trivial ultracategory $*$ to $\mathcal M$. That's the content of the paragraph following "The first question is..." - I was trying to identify those more concretely.

6-  I'm not sure what the nice objects are in the case of "models of a first order theory". Essentially these are the models $M$ such that for any two sets $J,K$, function $f: J\to \beta K$ and ultrafilter $\mathcal U$ on $J$, the canonical morphism $(\prod_K M)/\mathcal V \to \prod_J ((\prod_K M)/\mathcal f(j))/\mathcal U$ is an isomorphism, where $\mathcal V = \lim_\mathcal U f(j)$ in $\beta K$, equivalently $\mathcal U\wr \mathcal V_\bullet$ where $\mathcal V_\bullet = f$.

It looks like this map is always injective by definition of $\mathcal U\wr \mathcal V_\bullet$, but most likely almost never surjective. For instance take $K =*$, then this is $\mathcal M\to (\prod_J \mathcal M)/\mathcal U$, which is almost never surjective.

7- I'm sorry, I misunderstood that these were your main questions. So, for the question of which structures, this amounts to answering 6-. The answer seems to be "almost never" - my guess would be "if and only if $M=*$". It makes sense to a certain extent : what would be the compact Hausdorff topology on the set of elementary embeddings/morphisms ?

For the second question however, the way everything is set up makes it very easy to answer : a good point in $\mathcal M$ is an ultrafunctor $*\to \mathcal M$. This is clearly stable under composition of ultrafunctors : if $F:\mathcal{M\to N}$ is an ultrafunctor, so is $*\to \mathcal M\to\mathcal N$, and in particular, $F$ preserves "nice" objects. A corollary of how everything is set up is also (for free) that you get a morphism of ultramonoids (in the sense I described, so a morphism of compact Hausdorff topological monoids) $End(M)\to End(F(M))$.

8- By strongly connected I meant "only one isomorphism class". I'm not sure there is a standard terminology and what it is, if there is.

Comment: _Connected_ pointed categories? (as in, one isomorphism class)

Comment: I don’t fully understand this stuff, but is it too obvious to be worth including any tip about why ultracategories are not in general simply categories in compact Hausdorff spaces, if indeed they are not?

Comment: @KevinArlin : I was wondering about that too, and it seems I made a mistake - I didn't read the definition of ultracategory carefully enough. They are locally cartesian.fibrations, and only *certain* locally cartesian edges are closed under composition, not all of them. In particular most of what I said is not proved properly/potentially wrong

Comment: Even for monoids it starts getting wrong, because you're allowed some noninvertible transformations. Also, "pointed" becomes a more subtle structure.

Comment: @KevinArlin : it turns out I could fix my answer for the monoid case (a *pointed* ultracategory allows me to say more things than just an ultracategory with a point in $\mathcal M_*$). Hopefully with the new version of the answer, it is clearer what doesn't work for categories ! If not, I can add some more explicit words

Comment: @DavidRoberts : sorry I did not answer because I was trying to fix the mistake in my answer (which I think I managed to, for monoids). I'm not a big fan of "connected" for categories, maybe "strongly connected" would work.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Thanks for your partial answer! You argue that a monoid is not the same as a category with one object, but is the same as a pointed category with one object. What is a pointed category (nLab says it's a category with a zero object -- but this doesn't seem to be related to what you are saying) and how do you define the 2-category of pointed categories?

Comment: Are you saying the 1-category of monoids is equivalent to the 2-category of pointed categories? Or that the 2-category of monoids is equivalent to the 2-category of pointed categories? What is the 2-category of monoids?

Comment: "In particular, I'll interpret your question as [...]" What do you mean by that? *Which* question do you interpret? Do you use the same definition of "ultramonoid" as I do or not?

Comment: I have never seen this notation $*_{\beta I}\to \mathcal M_{\beta I}$. Would you mind recalling the notation you are using here? In my post I specifically referred to Definition 7 and not Definition 1. I don't even know what a Grothendieck fibration is.

Comment: How do you define the category of ultramonoids? Are the morphisms ultrafunctors or isomorphism classes of ultrafunctors?

Comment: What do you mean by "point"? (Of an ultracategory, say. You also talk about points of $\mathcal M_\ast$, but I don't even know what type of object that is.)

Comment: As I understand interpret your third last paragraph (I don't really understand all the words you are using: point, locally cartesian, comparison morphism, $\beta$, $^{fr}$, ...) you are saying that if $\mathcal M$ is an ultracategory and $M$ is a sufficiently nice object of $\mathcal M$, then $\mathrm{End}(M)$ can be considered as an ultramonoid. Can you say more concretely in the case $\mathcal M=$ the ultracategory of models of some-first order theory (with elementary embeddings as morphisms) when an object $M\in\mathcal M$ (i.e., a model) is sufficiently nice?

Comment: @DavidRoberts When is a pointed category connected and what do you mean by the question "Connected pointed categories?"?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Let me also add that (in my view) the two main questions of my post were 1) for which structures $\mathbf A$ the monoids $\mathrm{End}(\mathbf A)$ and $\mathrm{End}'(\mathbf A)$ carry the structure of an ultramonoid and 2) to what extent each ultrafunctor $F\colon\mathcal M\to\mathcal N$ induces for each $M\in\mathcal M$ (sufficiently nice, say) an ultrafunctor $\mathrm{End}(M)\to\mathrm{End}(F(M))$. Can you say anything about these questions? Do ultrafunctors preserves sufficiently nice objects after all?

Comment: @DavidRoberts I did some research. Do you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_category? (However, then I don't understand your "as in, one isomorphism class".)

Comment: @MaximeRamzi "I'm not a big fan of "connected" for categories, maybe "strongly connected" would work." What is a strongly connected category? Tried the nLab, but didn't find anything.

Comment: @user480841 I tried to answer your further questions in an edit.

Comment: @user480841 I meant what Maxime called strongly connected, not the wp definition,  which my clarification was meant to indicate. I put that query since monoids are equivalent to pointed categories with a single isomorphism class of objects, not just pointed categories.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Thanks!

Comment: @MaximeRamzi "it's unclear to me what "a category with one object" means" -> how are you then able to claim that "a monoid is not the same as a category with one object"?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Let me give two definitions: a *category with one object* is a category that has exactly one object; an *ultracategory with one object* is an ultracategory that has exactly one object.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi There are two definitions of "monoid". First definition: A *monoid* is a pointed category with one object up to isomorphism. Since pointed categories form a 2-category by definition, this yields a 2-category of monoids, but it turns out that this 2-category of monoids is equivalent to a 1-category. Second definition: A *monoid* is a small category with exactly one object. Here, "category" refers to an object of the 1-category of all small categories. Hence monoids in that sense form a 1-category too.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Comparison: These two definitions are equivalent, in the sense that one gets the same 1-category of monoids (no matter which definition one chooses). Now my question is: if we talk about *ultracategories* instead of *categories*, are these two definitions equivalent too? I guess if not, that's the origin of our misunderstanding: I tried to use a definition of "ultramonoid" along the lines of the second definition, whereas you used a definition of "ultramonoid" along the lines of the first definition.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi What do you mean by $*\to \mathcal M_*$ in your answer? Is it correct that you use the following definition of "ultramonoid": an *ultramonoid* is a pointed ultracategory $(\mathcal M, x\colon 1\to\mathcal M)$ such that the ultrafunctor $x$ is essentially surjective? Maybe it makes sense to call the whole thing $\mathcal M_*$, but you talk about $*\to \mathcal M_∗$ being "essentially surjective" -- this only makes sense when deleting the $*$ from $\mathcal M_*$ to me.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi In your original portion of the answer you use the phrase "the category of ultramonoids". I asked: "How do you define the category of ultramonoids?" Then in the clarifying comments you added that "I define the (2,1)-category of ultramonoids as a full subcategory of the category of pointed ultracategories (in the sense I described earlier)." But here you only say what the *(2,1)-category* of ultramonoids is and not what the *1-category* is.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Do you take the homotopy category of that (2,1)-category or is the situation similar to the situation with *categories* instead of *ultracategories* in which it happens by accident that the 2-category of pointed categories with one object up to isomorphism is equivalent to a 1-category?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi How would you define the term "pointed ultracategory" in the style of Definition 7 which I prefer?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi can "$x$ is an ultrafunctor from $1$ to an ultracategory $\mathcal M$" be characterized as "$x$ is an object of $\mathcal M$ with ... such that ..." similar to how one can characterize a point $1\to C$ of a *category* $C$ as being the same as an object of that category $C$?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Despite our misunderstanding of what the other means by "ultramonoid" (so that technically your answer does not answer the questions I intended to ask) let me say a big *thank you* to you, because understanding your perspective has been a great opportunity for me to learn some new terminology, and I appreciate your result that ultramonoids in your sense are monoids in compact Hausdorff topological spaces very much! :-)

Comment: @MaximeRamzi As for what the "main" questions of my post were, maybe I shouldn't have said that the $\mathrm{End}$ questions were the only main questions. The question what an ultramonoid is was also a major question, which you answered totally fine using your definition of ultramonoid. Maybe there isn't a nice answer with my definition of ultramonoid, so maybe that's the best one can say!

Comment: To answer your question, I don't think the two notions are equivalent for ultracategories. I call $\mathcal M_*$ what you would call $\mathcal M$, but that's just an artifact of Definition 1 vs 7. For your question about (2,1) vs 1, yes, part of my answer is the claim that this (2,1)-category is in fact equivalent to a 1-category - just as in the usual comparison of monoids and pointed categories.

Comment: To define pointed ultracategories in the style of definition 7, I would have to think about the translation from 1 to 7. What I *can* say ahead of doing this is that it would definitely be of the form " an $x$ in $\mathcal M$ satisfying such and such property" . So the data of an object + some condition

Comment: I *think*, but haven't worked the details, that an ultrafunctor $*\to \mathcal M$ should be the sane thing as an object $x\in \mathcal M$ such that all the transformations from (4) in Definition 7 are isomorphisms when evaluated at the constant $x$-valued $J$-indexed family. Does that condition make sense ?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Thank you for your repeated help. I learned a lot from our conversation!

Comment: @MaximeRamzi How would you define an ultra-preordered set? I would define it naively as an ultracategory whose underlying category happens to be a preorder. (Just as a would define an ultramonoid to be an ultracategory whose underlying category happens to have exactly one object.) Are you here using a different definition too when you say you haven't found a simple characterization of ultra-preordered sets?

Comment: For ultra preordered set, I think this is the only reasonable definition and I had the same in mind.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi I see!